# What does it mean to "replay" an HTTP request?

Tags: json, http, httprequest

When I was reading tutorials about working with HTTP requests/responses, I often read about "replaying" an HTTP request. However, I couldn't exactly understand what this meant. Does this mean just re-sending the HTTP request to the server?

Comment: Look up replay attack. Understanding a replay attack will help you understand replay in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A replay is when you capture a request, then modify parts of it and send it again.

We can use software like "WireShark", or browser dev tools "Network" tab in Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc. - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/

And now with the caught request you can modify any of the parameters and send it again. Let's say this website was using a param in their query string to figure out if logged in. For example: `http://google.com?isLoggedIn=false`. So I caught this and now I changed `isLoggedIn` to true. And now I can access his page as if I was logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Replay HTTP request means, sending and re-sending of HTTP request with some modification in the HTTP request body. For testing the requests and server side responses, tester's use to play with this back and forth action of HTTP request via tool sets, sometimes we can call it as replay attack. We can use burp, zap, postman, etc. Tools to do HTTP request body modification or to do HTTP replay.